# Multiple routing field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a newbie to elasticsearch. i need a clarification. i can understand how routing works, but I have a question.

Can i create routing for an document with multiple field. if yes, can i search the 
data using single routing value. Can any on provide any example about it.

Imagine I have 5 fields: `[username,id,age,dept,salary]`. Now i need to create a routing value for this document. Can I do so using the `username` and `id` field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow your question. Please explain more

Comment: @DrTech edited my question with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question: no, you can't automatically use multiple fields for a routing value when indexing a document.  You can choose one and only one field, and that field must contain a single value.

However, you could manually concatenate the `username` and `id` field and pass it in the indexing request:

```
PUT /index/type/id?routing=username_id
{ body }
```

That said, routing is a feature for more advanced users. It is very useful but does make life more complicated. You say that you're a newbie, so I'd suggest not playing with routing just yet.  That can follow when you're running a 50 node cluster.

Comment: I would like to search user data using username.Can i use routing or any other best way to do it??

Comment: Yes - all fields are indexed and searchable by default so you can search on any of those fields.  Routing is a different matter completely